# How to call database function into custom library in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a library and am trying to access the database through it in codeigniter.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

class History {

```
function __construct() {
    //$CI->load->database();
    //$this->load->library('database');
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();
}

public function create_history($id){
    //$this->load->database();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO inventory_history SELECT null,i.* FROM inventory i where i.inventory_id = :id";
    $query = $this->CI->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    return $query->execute();
}}
```

But I am getting error near the insert query. Going through Google I went around someone telling to use `$this->ci->db` to execute query. I'm not able to point out why there is error in database execution. How can I call database function into my custom library in codeigniter?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Undefined property: History::$CI

Answer (score 16, accepted):

is it this?

```
class YourLibName {
   private $CI;

   function __construct() {
       $this->CI =& get_instance();
       $this->CI->load->database();
   }

}
```

**Update**: I think you should not load and use database object in library. You better create model and call it from library instead. A library should be independent and can be used with other application.

Answer (score 3):

> In application/config/autoload.php add this :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); // add database in array
```

Same code for your library:

```
Class CutomLib
{
    function getData(){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $query  =   $CI->db->get('data');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

//your class 
  public function __construct()
  {

```
  $this->CI =& get_instance();
  $this->CI->load->database('default',TRUE);
```

}

//how to it inside function
  public function funcName(){

```
$query =   $this->CI->db->query("your QUERY");
$result = $query->result();

//what ever you want to do then
```

}

hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Although the topic is very old, but Just for the shake of new readers

```
function __construct() {
    //$CI->load->database();
    //$this->load->library('database');
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();
}
```

should be

```
function __construct() {
    //$CI->load->database();
    //$this->load->library('database');
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->database();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is how i managed to create custom database from user end without touching core files :

- First I made form to get all the details from user(More like Installing our application like wordpress do ).

  ```
  <?php echo form_open('your_controller_path'); ?> 
      <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" name="dbName" value="">
      <span class="help-block"><small><?php echo form_error('dbName'); ?>
      </small></span>
      <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" name="dbUsername" 
      value="">
      <span class="help-block"><small><?php echo form_error('dbUsername'); ?>
      </small></span>
      <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" name="dbPassword"  value="">
      <span class="help-block"><small><?php echo form_error('dbPassword'); ?>
      </small></span>
      <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" name="dbHostname" value="">
      <span class="help-block"><small><?php echo form_error('dbHostname'); ?></small></span>
      <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" name="dbPrefix" value="">
      <span class="help-block"><small><?php echo form_error('dbPrefix'); ?>
      </small></span>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
          Submit
      </button>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
  ```
- I fetch the details from controller and override default dsn before that load these in constructor:-

  - **$this->load->dbforge();**
  - **$this->load->dbutil();**

    ```
    if($this->dbutil->database_exists($this->input->post('dbName')))
    {
            echo $this->input->post('dbName')." Database Already Exist";
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->hostname = $this->input->post('dbHostname');
            $this->db->database = $this->input->post('dbName');
            $this->db->username = $this->input->post('dbUsername');
            $this->db->password = $this->input->post('dbPassword');
            $this->db->dbprefix = $this->input->post('dbPrefix');
            $dsn = 'dbdriver://'. $this->db->username.':'.$this->db->password.'@'.$this->db->hostname.'/'.$this->db->database;
            if(!$this->load->database($dsn))
            {
                if ($this->dbforge->create_database($this->input->post('dbName')))
                {
                        echo 'Database created!';
                        $this->db->db_select($this->input->post('dbName'));
                }
            }else
            {
                echo "Sorry Connection Problem : ".$dsn ;
            }
        }
    ```

I Hope it Help